# Laravel dynamic redirect (rewrite) from database

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5, url-rewriting

I want let admin create pairs of urls in the special table.

For example, we have a link **example.com/cars/bmw?sort=desc&color=white&price_from=999999999&limit=20**

Admin wants to give an access to this page by **example.com/bmw-cool**.

So if user goes on first link he get the appropriate content but his url changes to second. If he goes straight on second link he gives the same content under the second url.

What is the best way to create a such redirect/rewrite table?

Answer (score 0):

You would add this in your `routes.php` file:

```
// in routes.php
Route::get('/bmw-cool', function () {
    return redirect('cars/bmw?sort=desc&color=white&price_from=999999999&limit=20');
});
```

Comment: in this case i have just a usual redirect with url changin but i want to save /bmw-cool in address bar

Comment: then you're better off using an `.htaccess` redirect -- you can follow this tutorial:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/

Comment: this is the same
it will just redirect me to another page but i do not want to change the url

Comment: you're better off creating a route for `bmw-cool` and passing this to a controller method that would then add the parameters to the `cars/bmw` method.